# Scalatest building and running in Intellij, but not building the project when run on the command line with maven

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, scalatest

I'm able to run my tests in a spec file individually when using intellij, however when I try running with Maven on the command line the project will not build with a

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load a Suite class that was
>   discovered in the runpath: project.uitest.spec.aTestFile

error.  I've tried restarting everything I can think of, and it works fine on my coworkers computer that has been running the tests for a long time.  The issue reproduces on two other new coworkers environments however.

We tried copying the .m2 folder from the working environment onto the new environment machines however still run into the same issue.

We are using the same version of the JRE, and the scala and scalatest versions are specified in our pom.xml file.

We can also ignore the test that won't load and are able to run the tests.

Any insight or ideas of ways to fix this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What version of ScalaTest are you using?

[ScalaTest Maven Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest-maven-plugin) 1.0 doesn't support ScalaTest 3

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-maven-plugin/issues/27